# Display nicely across desktop screen sizes

Tags: css, responsive-design, font-size

I have designed a website on my retina monitor, set at the highest resolution. On this resolution the site looks really great :p. However, when I view the site on a smaller 13" monitor, all the elements and the font are way too big and in your face.

I have done some research, and found two ways to try and show the website in a nice way across different desktop screen sizes:

1. Use a media query to Scale/Transform the body. However, this "feels" wrong and I can imagine this has some performance impact. Furthermore I can imagine this gives inconsistencies across screen sizes
2. Use ems across the board. I am not really sure what'd be the right starting point for this, but I have read that some people base everything upon their font-size. However, I would not really know how this'd work for images.

Can someone please tell me what'd the best way to make the website display nicely across desktop screen size.

p.s. The website is based on twitter bootstrap

Comment: It would be easier to give you hints if we could see a fiddle. However, using media queries is not a wrong approach, just don't expect that simply scaling the elements will solve you problems.

Comment: Could you suggest what to put in the fiddle? I am not really sure since it is a site-wide problem..

Comment: Would be possible to put the whole site? At least the HTML and the CSS so we can see the site layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the second option. The way it would work is by setting the  element font size in px, and using relative sizes for the containers and divs inside them.
For example

```
<body>
 <div id="container">
  <article>This is some text</article>
 </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html{
 font-size: 32px;
}
#container{
 font-size: 1.5 rem;
}
article{
 font-size: 1.2 em;
}
```

CSS-tricks has a nice article on this - http://css-tricks.com/rems-ems/

As for image resizing, that can be done dynamically in JS based on window.width()

Comment: I used this option in combination with `html { font-size: 62,5% }`. As default font size is 16px in most browsers. This means that 0.1rem == 1px. This made it much more easy to convert all values in px to rems